# Is There A Way to Store Multiple Model in A ForeignKey Field in Django?

Tags: python, django

Currently looking at Django documentation, but I could not find something satisfying my requirements. Assuming I have a schema as below:

**Models:** A, B

The fields on A are not that important. However, I want a field on B just like below:

```
B:
    references = [A1, A2, A3]
```

To put it short, I need to store multiple model-instances of A in `references` field of B.

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) declares three different solutions to store another model-instance in a field of a model:

> class ForeignKey(othermodel, **options)
>
> class ManyToManyField(othermodel, **options)
>
> class OneToOneField(othermodel, parent_link=False, **options)

And those take only `othermodel` argument, not a multiple one.

I know that Django currently supports relational databases (which have column-row logic) and what I want is recursion or reference as array in a cell, but I wanted to hear your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the ManyToManyField is for.

Comment: Then should I say `B.references = [A1, A2]` then save?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, if you don't need A to also be able to reference multiple Bs, you could just use a ForeignKey from A to B; the reverse relationship works in the same way.